# SQL output two rows using one entry

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to output two rows in a one entry but with two tables. here is my table:

table_A

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
checkkey      checknum       confirmed      printed    canceled
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1               1               Y             Y           Y
2               2               Y             Y           N
3               10              N             Y           Y
```

table_B

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
checkkey      checknum       status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1               1               V           
2               2               V          
3               10              V
```

I want an output like this

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
checkkey      checknum       confirmed      printed    canceled  status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1               1               Y             Y           Y
1               1               Y             Y           Y        V
2               2               Y             Y           N
2               2               Y             Y           N        V
3               10              N             Y           Y
3               10              N             Y           Y        V
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a UNION , first query will get all with status as V based on tableB and second one gets all rows from A

```
select a.checkkey, a.checknum,a.confirmed, a.printed,a.canceled,  b.status
from table_A a
inner join table_B b
on a.checkkey = b.checkkey
union all
select a.checkkey, a.checknum,a.confirmed, a.printed,a.canceled, NULL as status
from table_A a
order by checkkey, checknum;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select a.*, 'V' as status
from table_A a
union all
select a.*, NULL as status
from table_A a
order by checkkey, checknum;
```

`Table_B` doesn't seem necessary at all.

Comment: yes, the status column probably has information, and you are ignoring it.

Comment: @Troveldom . . . Not according to the posted question.  This answer returns exactly the results requested by the OP.

Comment: You are right, your answer is correct as he specifies that those are exactly the tables. The answer could be better though

Comment: @Troveldom . . . I would actually like to hear from the OP.  The question is quite ambiguous and this seems like the simplest solution for achieving what s/he wants.